# Cycling through Spaces?

Tags: macos, spaces

Is there a way that when you cycle through the last Space, it cycles you back to the first one?

And, if you cycle backwards and get to the first space, have it cycle back to the last?

Right now, it stops as at the end and beginning, and I'd love to just keep on swiping to cycle.

Comment: That's how it works in Snow Leopard but not in Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cycle functionality does not exist but when you arrive to the last one you can activate the shortcut to jump to the first one from Keyboard/Shortcuts in the System Preferences.

[image]